# How to execute php shell commands from browser?

Tags: php, shell, unix, php-7.3

I'm trying to execute some shell commands from browser. But whenever i do so, I get "php is not recognized as external or internal command" error whereas it works fine in the terminal. I tried looking for it on the web and found something related to "www-data" user which I couldn't possibly understand. Can you please help me figure out what could be the issue with the given below code?

```
<?php

shell_exec("php -r \"copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');\"");
        shell_exec("php composer-setup.php --install-dir=" . $this->binPath . " --filename=composer");
        shell_exec("php -r \"unlink('composer-setup.php');\"");
```

I'm expecting the shell_exec command to download and install composer for me at the desired location.

Comment: Does `php -v` work in terminal?

Comment: Try using the full path to PHP on the `shell_exec` calls.

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa Yes it works.

Comment: @Dave it needs to work for all platforms so I am trying to make it dynamic rather than for single platform.

Comment: Not sure that's going to be feasible since every platform may have a different path to where PHP is and may or may not allow the use of `shell_exec`.